# Load data from one table to another in hive

Tags: pyspark, hive, apache-spark-sql, hiveql, create-table

I have a table in hive named a.table1 which has columns id, name, class and it is fully loaded with data.

```
id name class 
1   a     1
11  b     14
```

I want to create a new table b.table2 from a.table1 which which have fields id, name, class, status.
When id is less than 10 the class and status would have same value else value would be 0.

```
id name class status
1   a     1     1
11  b     14    0
```

What I am doing is, creating a table :

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS b.table2(
id BIGINT,
name string,
class int,
status int
)
```

How can i load the contents of the table? Or is there any better way to do it?

```
spark = SparkSession.builder.enableHiveSupport().getOrCreate()
sc = spark.sparkContext
sqlContext = spark._wrapped
```

Answer (score 1):

Just do a select and insert the results into table2:

```
insert into b.table2 (
    select *, case when id < 10 then class else 0 end as status from a.table1
);
```

Answer (score 1):

[CTAS](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/LanguageManual+DDL#LanguageManualDDL-CreateTableAsSelect(CTAS)) will do create and load table in single statement:

```
CREATE TABLE table2 AS
 select id, name, class, status 
   from table1;
```